# how to decode videofile

Tags: android, video, decoding

In the decoding of the image file we use BitmapFactory then instead of this what we can use for video?

```
       public void decodeFile(String filePath) {
            // Decode image size

            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

            // The new size we want to scale to
            //final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            //int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            /*while (true) {
                if (width_tmp &lt;REQUIRED_SIZE &amp;&amp; height_tmp &lt; REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }*/
            //int scale = 1;
            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            //o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);

            //imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
```

Comment: here i m selecting the video from the gallary n get the path from the sdcard for the particular video and i am storing the path in the "filePath"

Answer (score 0):

There are no APIs for "decoding" video in the Android SDK, other than to play it back (e.g., `MediaPlayer`). You are welcome to try to find some third-party library that offers you whatever functionality it is that you seek.